# Angularjs directives: Binding function from wrapped directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive `inner` which I want to wrap into another directive `comp` to hide some complexity of inner directive. "Comp" defines the `clickAction` which should be executed by the "inner" directive.

Now I have some troubles to bind correctly to the "clickAction" of inner directive from comp directive.

If I explicitly apply `click-action="clickAction()"` it's works, but not desired in that way.

```
template: '<inner ng-model="data" click-action="clickAction()"></inner>',
```

I think I have to add some "magic" in the link function to bind to the `clickAction`

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AXf1oL?p=preview

1) How can I achieve this (simple) scenario.
2) Is this the right approach to "wrap" the inner directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap `clickAction` with another function inside "inner" directive scope.

Comp directive has no changes.

```
app.directive('comp', [function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            data: '=ngModel'
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<inner ng-model="data" click-action="clickAction()"></inner>',
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
               scope.clickAction = function() {
                alert('click');
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

`inner` directive should have function with diferent name from "clickAction" which calls this action:

```
app.directive('inner', [function() {
    return {
      scope: {
          data: '=ngModel',
          clickAction: '&',
      },
      require: ['ngModel'],
      restrict: 'AE',
      //replace: true, // optional 
      template: '<div ng-click="onClick()">{{data.value}}</div',
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
          scope.onClick = function(){
            alert('inner');
            scope.clickAction();  
          };
        }
  };
}]);
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y9OoK0tGqTWlXNFEZuDr?p=preview

If you want to pass arguments between function you can do it by using:

Template:

```
template: '<inner ng-model="data" click-action="clickAction(params)"></inner>',
```

Click action:

```
scope.clickAction = function(params) {
    alert(params);
};
```

Click action inside inner directive:

```
scope.onClick = function(){
    alert('inner');
    scope.clickAction({params: "yo dawg!"});  
};
```

Ad. your question: I don't see anything wrong in placing directive inside directive.

**EDIT**

If you dont want to define `click-action=clickAction()` you shouldn't create isolated scope in `inner` directive. Then your inner directive will use scope of `outer` directive and also u will not need to wrap clickAction() with another function.

There is plunkr with this solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/jKg1R4Bn3TvZPOTLtLZn?p=preview

Comment: thanks for your answer!

Maybe the first question was not good descriped. I try to find a way without defining the attribute `click-action="clickAction()"` on the outer scope. 

http://plnkr.co/edit/ixEKxw?p=preview 

I don't want to define explicitly the click-action on the comp template, possible?

Comment: Sorry, everythink ok (maybe I should go to bed earlier). I mixed up the comp. template with the definition of `<comp ng-model="data"></comp>`

Comment: I've updated my answer - not using isolated scope inside inner directive should help. Please accept my post as an answer if it helped ;)